# IIS 7.5 w3wp process randomly throws ThreadInterruptedException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm working on a MVC4 application. It runs on IIS 7.5.7600. At random time intervals w3wp process throws ThreadInterruptedException with this trace. I have no idea where or why this happens. Does anyone out there have any idea?

```
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/FiscalPower-188-130247532528202235</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Thread was interrupted from a waiting state.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CleanupCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException: Thread was interrupted from a waiting state.
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CleanupCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is when the tcp connection has been closed before your code has been able to finish to return data. IE: your user pressed F5.